# Make vsftpd accept simple ftp connections

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, ftp

...instead of sftp
Right now ftp-ing to my server works great with sftp over port 22, but there are times when i'm on my home network and don't need the extra ssh layer. Also, I suspect that not being able to connect on regular ftp:21 is constantly making a backup program timeout
Here's my config:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
anon_upload_enable=NO
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
tcp_wrappers=YES
max_clients=4
max_per_ip=1
listen_port=21
pasv_enable=YES
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you allow FTP through your local packet filter (firewall). Edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` or run `system-config-firewall`.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple VSFTPD.conf allowing login from local users.

```
# No anonymous login
anonymous_enable=NO
# Let local users login
# If you connect from the internet with local users, you should enable TLS/SSL/FTPS
local_enable=YES

# Write permissions
write_enable=YES

# Chroot all Users
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO
```

Remember FTP Passwords are transferred **unencrypted**. Read up on enabling SSL/TLS/FTPS.

Comment: Somehow this still doesn't allow me to connect, it times out. Does filezilla allow non sftp connections? does vsftpd ?

Comment: Simple question: Did you start it? `ps aux | grep vsftpd`

Comment: vsftpd does not handle the sftp connection - SSHD does. You probably forgot to start vsftpd. Both vsftpd and filezilla allow non sftp connections.